# Flutter Web change displayed URL

Tags: javascript, flutter, url, flutter-web

In my Flutter-Web project I need to display my URL without `#`.

Example: `test.com/#/page` -> `test.com/page`

I used `html.window.history.pushState(null, "Page", "/page");` for long time and it worked. But things must have had changed and this not results in `test.com/page#/page`.

I looked into https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3324 but did not find any solution.

Is there any other way to archive this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which I do not quite understand so if anybody can explain this please edit my answer.

`Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => window.history.pushState(null, "Page", "/page"));`

Answer (score 0):

just use this library.
If you want to remove the leading hash (#) from the URL of your Flutter web app,

https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy